# Reading data from a .wav file using only native python

Tags: python, native, wav

I am attempting to write a program that detects the frequency of a sound in a .wav file.  I would like to do this with exclusively native python, no third-party modules.  I used the built-in read() and open() functions and got some strange results:

```
with open('pcm-test.wav', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read(255)
print data
```

When I run it, I get this:

```
>>> 
RIFF$ÈWAVEfmt data
>>>
```

What am I doing wrong?  Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

*EDIT*

I suppose I phrased this wrong.  I'm looking for the frequency of the tone in the .wav file, not the sample rate.  I have an algorithm for computing frequency based on an array of amplitudes, but I have no way of finding it.  I guess my question would be how can I get raw amplitude data from the .wav file and store it as a list, tuple, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> > What am I doing wrong?

Nothing, everything works just fine. Next, parse the WAVE header (http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/) and get your sample rate.